# Como posso fazer pequisa entre datas com nodejs e mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer pesquisa entre datas.

Exemplo:

Trazer todos os dados entre 06/12/2018 a 06/11/2019.

Trazer todos os dados de um determinado ano ou mês.

Como posso fazer esses filtros no meu controller com nodejs e mongodb?

Eu tentei da seguinte maneira mas não obtive êxito, segue o método index da class PedidoController:

```
async index(req, res) {

const filters = {};

// filtro de pesquisa
if (req.query.data_min) {
  filters.createdAt.$gte = req.query.data_min;
}

const userLogado = await User.findById(req.userId);

// se não for um provedor
if (userLogado.provedor !== true) {
  const pedidos = await Pedido.find({
    cliente: req.userId
  }).populate("cliente");

  return res.json(pedidos);
}

const pedidos = await Pedido.paginate(filters, {
  page: req.params.id,
  limit: 10,
  populate: ["cliente"],
  sort: "-createdAt"
});

return res.json(pedidos);
```

}

Comment: tem alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não, ele retorna normal como se n tivesse o filtro..

Comment: Tente converter o valor `req.params.data_min` para o tipo `Date`

Comment: @MarceloVismari tentei isso mas sem sucesso, acho que é porque o meu createdAt esta salvo no formato Datetime (2019-12-24T16:42:11.669Z) no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz a seguinte alteração na minha condição de pesquisa e aparentemente esta funcionando como eu gostaria. Utilizei a lib  `date-fns-timezone` para formatar a data (não necessariamente seria necessário formatar a data) só utilizei para deixar por padrão a data_max com 23 horas,dessa forma posso fazer pesquisa de um determinado dia específico, podendo colocar a mesma data no meu campo de data_min e data_max e ele me retornara todos os dados de 00:00 horas a 23:00 horas. Isso foi feito porque por padrão o mongodb pede um data mínima e uma data máxima para poder fazer pesquisa entre datas. Segue o código da alteração.

```
if (req.query.data_min || req.query.data_max) {
  filters.createdAt = {};

  const dataMinFormatada = formatToTimeZone(
    req.query.data_min,
    "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
    {
      timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"
    }
  );

  const dataMaxFormatada = formatToTimeZone(
    req.query.data_max,
    "YYYY-MM-DDT23:mm:ss.SSSZ",
    {
      timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"
    }
  );


  filters.createdAt.$gte = dataMinFormatada;
  filters.createdAt.$lte = dataMaxFormatada;
}
```